# Sharepoint 2010 - Site Template doesn't show in new Web Collection dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sitetemplate

I am developing new SiteTemplate project in VS 2010. I didn't change anything, and I clicked Deploy to check if it is working on my SP server. And it doesn't ...

Why isn't it working? Plz, help.

I'm developing on Client system (Windows 7) - i have installed autonomous instance of Sharepoint. I haven't changed anything in SP central admin, i also checked folders in  *C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates* and files deployed successfully...

Any suggestions for solving problem will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are three properties that control a site template's visibility:

- [`IsHidden`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebtemplate.ishidden.aspx) that controls the visibility of the site template in the UI;
- [`IsRootWebOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebtemplate.isrootwebonly.aspx) that determines if the site template is available for site collection root web site only;
- [`IsSubWebOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebtemplate.issubwebonly.aspx) that determines if the web template is available for sub-web sites only.

Mostly likely the problem is due to improper setting of one of these properties.